# Is there a standard for writing device drivers for microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, driver, device

I have written device drivers for microcontrollers using AUTOSAR. But I was interested in knowing if there are other standards for device drivers. I am planning to write for TIVA TM4C123GH6PM. It has an ARM Cortex-M4F Processor Core.

My main goal is to write drivers that could be used by others too, and wouldn't require much knowledge of the hardware from them.

Answer (score 3):

For ARM Cortex-M processors there is the CMSIS (the Cortex-M Software Interface Standard). CMSIS is intended to provide a standard method for hardware abstraction that can be used by any Cortex-M vendor. TI almost certainly has created some software that provides CMSIS support for their processors, so you should also look for that. The CMSIS documentation and templates are available from [cmsis.arm.com](http://cmsis.arm.com)