# Unified Driver model for low speed and high speed microcontrollers with limited and good memory

Tags: driver, device

I am trying to develop an experimental RTOS. I am stuck in the driver layer design. I want to make the driver layer libraries friendly for the other layers but then again I would like to have high performance.
  I have narrowed this down to a mixture of 2 approaches. The first is to have a structure for the controller with callbacks as elements.
 For eg:

```
struct peripheral_controller { 
    int32_t (*init) (struct peripheral_instance_regs *peripheral_instance_regs);
    int32_t (*isFull) (struct peripheral_instance_regs *peripheral_instance_regs);
};
```

The second approach is to have helper macros which take the peripheral_instance_regs as arguements.

For eg:

```
#define isFull(reg)
 (reg&0x01 == 1)
```

Is this the right approach? Will it confuse the users of my library? The problem with the callbacks as I see is in the interrupt routine where I would not want to call any functions.

Answer (score 1):

(See also [Is there a standard for writing device drivers for microcontrollers?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101247/is-there-a-standard-for-writing-device-drivers-for-microcontrollers?rq=1) ; as your question relates purely to software you might get a better answer on the software stackexchange.)

In C, functions are *strongly* preferred over macros wherever possible. They're easier to debug, and can inline just as well if you're concerned about speed. You say "in the interrupt routine where I would not want to call any functions"; what target platform are you writing for and do you have a hard stack limit? Banning functions entirely from interrupt handlers is not a great style either. You might want to invest in a "top half"/"bottom half" architecture as used by Linux.

Having said that, the quasi-object-orientated style (I wouldn't call it "callback") of passing a map of peripheral registers around doesn't work well on the very small platforms such as PIC, where indirection is unreasonably expensive. Those are really too small for a meaningful operating system with drivers.

Comment: That platform I am writing to will vary from Cortex M3 to ARM SoC. The OS is just baremetal. In the case of not calling functions I do not want latency in the ISR. I was thinking of the top and bottom half but I am not sure whether that too can be accomplished without calling a function to clear off the interrupt registers. For cases like the PIC the above applies as the my above system is just baremetal with 1 or more tasks. What I am concerned about is a good Hardware abstraction layer design.

Comment: Function call latency need not be high and they can be inlined. In an RTOS your concern is worst-case latency, remember.

Comment: Inline again depends upon the compilers decision, correct? The problem is with smaller microcontroller such as MSP430 where a function call inside the ISR is too costly. I have decided on having something like UART_Send_Byte(UART_Instance instance); prototype as my HAL rather than go the callback way. A person who would want to port can just reimplement UART_Send_Byte for his particular hardware.